# Is it possible to define a macro in which "(' is escaped?

Tags: c

Can I define a macro like:

```
#define ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL,SUB_LEVEL printf(
```

Compiler complain this line expecting a `;`. Is there a way to escape the "("?

This is intended to replace a function:

```
  ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL,SUB_LEVEL
          "error, there is an error %d\n",
           error_id);
```

with a C built-in function

```
  printf("error, there is an error %d\n",
         error_id);
```

EDIT:  I just want to replace one "(", not include ")". The reason why I ask this is that there are already some codes as posted in question, so I just want to replace one line like ERROR_REPROT(... with printf( .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you use [variadic macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html):

```
#define ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL, SUB_LEVEL, ...) \
    printf(__VA_ARGS__)
```

While you can put whatever you want as the replacement for a macro, you define it wrong:

```
#define ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL,SUB_LEVEL   printf(
/*      Error with missing `)` here ^ */
```

The preprocessor needs the closing parenthesis, or it will cause errors in the preprocessing phase.

Also when you are using this macro you can't do as you do:

```
ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL,SUB_LEVEL
      "error, there is an error %d\n",
       error_id);
```

The preprocessor will throw an error here too as there is no comma between the `SUB_LEVEL` argument and the string.

So the answer to the question if you can replace a single left parenthesis is simply no, you can't.

Comment: Thank. But I just want to replace one "(", not include ")". The reason why I ask this is that there are already some code as posted in question, so I just want to replace one line like ERROR_REPROT(... with printf( .

Comment: @Joe.Z You simply can not do what you want to do. The pre-processor needs the closing parenthesis after the argument list, and you can not add arguments as you do in the "call" to the macro.

Comment: I think this might not satisfy the underlying problem of the question, because it requires that SUB_LEVEL appear as an argument to the macro. However, in the original source text, there is no comma between SUB_LEVEL and the format string. I suspect SUB_LEVEL expanded to a string, which the compiler concatenated with the format string. Perhaps this can be dealt with by using #undef to remove the SUB_LEVEL definition and using #define to give it a new value (perhaps the null string).

Comment: @Joe.Z: Joachim Pileborg’s answer attempts to solve your underlying problem (replacing the `ERROR_REPORT(LEVEL,SUB_LEVEL` text) by using a mechanism (`__VA_ARGS__`) other than the one you proposed. The method you proposed, defining a macro to consume a left parenthesis, will not work, but there may be other ways to solve your problem.